# how to get wall/news feed/user image of Facebook via Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Are there any clues how I can get the following stuff of Facebook

1. Wall
2. News Feed
3. User picture

???
Which kind of requests I have to use?

I've tried

```
dynamic p = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get(userID + "/posts");

dynamic p = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get(userID + "/feed");
```

But it seems returns the same thing...

To get user I use

```
user = new FacebookUser();
dynamic u = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get(userID);

user.ID = u.id;
user.Name = u.name;
user.FirstName = u.first_name;
user.LastName = u.last_name;
user.Link = u.link;
user.Gender = u.gender;
user.Locale = u.locale;
```

But it has no picture link. (http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started doesn't help)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys, finally I found the approach how to do it.

First of all you have to navigate here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
to experiment :)

Technically ypu have to apply allpermissions you have and use 
i.e. https://graph.facebook.com/your_profile_id/feed to get the your feed.

The list of permission are available here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

URL to get user picture you have to build like

https://graph.facebook.com/your_profile_id/picture

Have fun! :)